Export able to export to csv using Highcharts Vue
I have a simple chart, I want the export-data to export the data to CSV. But I do not see that option. What is wrong with my code:
main.js:
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import HighchartsVue from "highcharts-vue";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HighchartsAccessibility from "highcharts/modules/accessibility";
import HighchartsExporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
import HighchartsExportData from "highcharts/modules/export-data";
import mapInit from "highcharts/modules/map";
import mapData from "@highcharts/map-collection/custom/world.geo.json";

mapInit(Highcharts);

Highcharts.maps["myMapName"] = mapData;

HighchartsAccessibility(Highcharts);
HighchartsExportData(Highcharts);
HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);

Vue.use(HighchartsVue);

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  render: (h) => h(App),
});


MapChart.vue:
<template>
  <highcharts
    :constructor-type="'mapChart'"
    :options="mapOptions"
    class="map"
  ></highcharts>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      mapOptions: {
        chart: {
          map: "myMapName",
        },
        title: {
          text: "World Map",
        },
        accessibility: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        mapNavigation: {
          enabled: true,
          buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: "bottom",
          },
        },
        colorAxis: {
          min: 3,
          minColor: "#efecf3",
          maxColor: "#990041",
          max: 17246092,
        },
        tooltip: {},
        series: [
          {
            colorKey: "visits",
            data: [
              {
                country: "Albania",
                visits: 53441,
              },
              {
                country: "Algeria",
                visits: 9304,
              },
              {
                country: "Argentina",
                visits: 77321,
              },
              {
                country: "Armenia",
                visits: 41661,
              },
              {
                country: "Australia",
                visits: 1363119,
              },
              {
                country: "Austria",
                visits: 353288,
              },
              {
                country: "Azerbaijan",
                visits: 48111,
              },
              {
                country: "Belarus",
                visits: 17638,
              },
              {
                country: "Belgium",
                visits: 224227,
              },
              {
                country: "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                visits: 30180,
              },
              {
                country: "Brazil",
                visits: 258577,
              },
              {
                country: "Bulgaria",
                visits: 151502,
              },
              {
                country: "Canada",
                visits: 1183894,
              },
              {
                country: "China",
                visits: 105676,
              },
              {
                country: "Colombia",
                visits: 178806,
              },
              {
                country: "Croatia",
                visits: 45416,
              },
              {
                country: "Cyprus",
                visits: 5498,
              },
              {
                country: "Czech Republic",
                visits: 909352,
              },
              {
                country: "Denmark",
                visits: 174967,
              },
              {
                country: "Dominican Republic",
                visits: 18860,
              },
              {
                country: "Egypt",
                visits: 46024,
              },
              {
                country: "Estonia",
                visits: 41401,
              },
              {
                country: "Faroe Islands",
                visits: 92,
              },
              {
                country: "Finland",
                visits: 82992,
              },
              {
                country: "France",
                visits: 1491268,
              },
              {
                country: "Georgia",
                visits: 156395,
              },
              {
                country: "Germany",
                visits: 2553098,
              },
              {
                country: "Greece",
                visits: 46171,
              },
              {
                country: "Guatemala",
                visits: 56040,
              },
              {
                country: "Hong Kong SAR of China",
                visits: 711130,
              },
              {
                country: "Hungary",
                visits: 71749,
              },
              {
                country: "Iceland",
                visits: 2114,
              },
              {
                country: "India",
                visits: 2868572,
              },
              {
                country: "Ireland",
                visits: 207269,
              },
              {
                country: "Israel",
                visits: 61145,
              },
              {
                country: "Italy",
                visits: 823319,
              },
              {
                country: "Japan",
                visits: 4810408,
              },
              {
                country: "Kazakhstan",
                visits: 119304,
              },
              {
                country: "Latvia",
                visits: 25391,
              },
              {
                country: "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya",
                visits: 5555,
              },
              {
                country: "Lithuania",
                visits: 21681,
              },
              {
                country: "Luxembourg",
                visits: 8703,
              },
              {
                country: "Macedonia",
                visits: 405473,
              },
              {
                country: "Malaysia",
                visits: 117930,
              },
              {
                country: "Maldives",
                visits: 1266,
              },
              {
                country: "Moldova",
                visits: 24425,
              },
              {
                country: "Monaco",
                visits: 243,
              },
              {
                country: "Montenegro",
                visits: 17042,
              },
              {
                country: "Netherlands",
                visits: 2479834,
              },
              {
                country: "New Zealand",
                visits: 50603,
              },
              {
                country: "Nigeria",
                visits: 1698638,
              },
              {
                country: "Norway",
                visits: 227112,
              },
              {
                country: "Oman",
                visits: 9053,
              },
              {
                country: "Pakistan",
                visits: 347628,
              },
              {
                country: "Philippines",
                visits: 132262,
              },
              {
                country: "Poland",
                visits: 413068,
              },
              {
                country: "Portugal",
                visits: 102477,
              },
              {
                country: "Qatar",
                visits: 14202,
              },
              {
                country: "Romania",
                visits: 317966,
              },
              {
                country: "Russian Federation",
                visits: 41468,
              },
              {
                country: "San Marino",
                visits: 37,
              },
              {
                country: "Saudi Arabia",
                visits: 95093,
              },
              {
                country: "Serbia",
                visits: 334413,
              },
              {
                country: "Singapore",
                visits: 7602997,
              },
              {
                country: "Slovakia (Slovak Republic)",
                visits: 52697,
              },
              {
                country: "Slovenia",
                visits: 8482,
              },
              {
                country: "South Africa",
                visits: 784150,
              },
              {
                country: "South Korea",
                visits: 312954,
              },
              {
                country: "Spain",
                visits: 904582,
              },
              {
                country: "Sri Lanka",
                visits: 8116,
              },
              {
                country: "Sweden",
                visits: 1048527,
              },
              {
                country: "Switzerland",
                visits: 1296541,
              },
              {
                country: "Taiwan region",
                visits: 247804,
              },
              {
                country: "Thailand",
                visits: 416014,
              },
              {
                country: "Turkey",
                visits: 178539,
              },
              {
                country: "Ukraine",
                visits: 774568,
              },
              {
                country: "United Arab Emirates",
                visits: 104290,
              },
              {
                country: "United States of America",
                visits: 2519207,
              },
              {
                country: "United States",
                visits: 17246092,
              },
              {
                country: "Uruguay",
                visits: 7354,
              },
              {
                country: "Bangladesh",
                visits: 67672,
              },
              {
                country: "Bolivia",
                visits: 21636,
              },
              {
                country: "Cambodia",
                visits: 1132839,
              },
              {
                country: "Chile",
                visits: 30753,
              },
              {
                country: "Ethiopia",
                visits: 337233,
              },
              {
                country: "Malta",
                visits: 4881,
              },
              {
                country: "Mexico",
                visits: 188870,
              },
              {
                country: "Puerto Rico",
                visits: 11073,
              },
              {
                country: "Somalia",
                visits: 101789,
              },
              {
                country: "South Sudan",
                visits: 5583,
              },
              {
                country: "Venezuela",
                visits: 431902,
              },
              {
                country: "Viet Nam",
                visits: 731114,
              },
              {
                country: "Angola",
                visits: 75691,
              },
              {
                country: "Antigua and Barbuda",
                visits: 309,
              },
              {
                country: "Costa Rica",
                visits: 27307,
              },
              {
                country: "Ecuador",
                visits: 72013,
              },
              {
                country: "El Salvador",
                visits: 35544,
              },
              {
                country: "Iraq",
                visits: 114778,
              },
              {
                country: "Kuwait",
                visits: 9479,
              },
              {
                country: "Kyrgyzstan",
                visits: 19661,
              },
              {
                country: "Lebanon",
                visits: 4668,
              },
              {
                country: "Morocco",
                visits: 13166,
              },
              {
                country: "Panama",
                visits: 25031,
              },
              {
                country: "Zambia",
                visits: 12664,
              },
              {
                country: "Andorra",
                visits: 306,
              },
              {
                country: "Chad",
                visits: 4705,
              },
              {
                country: "Cuba",
                visits: 16800,
              },
              {
                country: "Ghana",
                visits: 30881,
              },
              {
                country: "Indonesia",
                visits: 1902195,
              },
              {
                country: "Jordan",
                visits: 5312,
              },
              {
                country: "Kenya",
                visits: 112430,
              },
              {
                country: "Macau SAR of China",
                visits: 15691,
              },
              {
                country: "Mongolia",
                visits: 4563,
              },
              {
                country: "Nepal",
                visits: 10716,
              },
              {
                country: "Peru",
                visits: 63266,
              },
              {
                country: "Rwanda",
                visits: 54039,
              },
              {
                country: "Tunisia",
                visits: 4190,
              },
              {
                country: "Uzbekistan",
                visits: 68575,
              },
              {
                country: "Saint Kitts and Nevis",
                visits: 133,
              },
              {
                country: "Tajikistan",
                visits: 11662,
              },
              {
                country: "Democratic Republic of The Congo",
                visits: 25806,
              },
              {
                country: "Barbados",
                visits: 685,
              },
              {
                country: "Cape Verde",
                visits: 5754,
              },
              {
                country: "Iran (Islamic Republic of)",
                visits: 43079,
              },
              {
                country: "Equatorial Guinea",
                visits: 615,
              },
              {
                country: "Liechtenstein",
                visits: 135,
              },
              {
                country: "Bonaire/Sint Eustatius/Saba",
                visits: 100,
              },
              {
                country: "Burundi",
                visits: 18386,
              },
              {
                country: "Aland Islands",
                visits: 48,
              },
              {
                country: "Syrian Arab Republic",
                visits: 3407,
              },
              {
                country: "Belize",
                visits: 645,
              },
              {
                country: "Guadeloupe",
                visits: 252,
              },
              {
                country: "Guinea-Bissau",
                visits: 4325,
              },
              {
                country: "Holy See (Vatican City State)",
                visits: 95,
              },
              {
                country: "Honduras",
                visits: 18958,
              },
              {
                country: "British Virgin Islands",
                visits: 947,
              },
              {
                country: "Cote D Ivoire",
                visits: 18164,
              },
              {
                country: "Lao Peoples Democratic Republic",
                visits: 22122,
              },
              {
                country: "Mauritius",
                visits: 2613,
              },
              {
                country: "Seychelles",
                visits: 4175,
              },
              {
                country: "Bahrain",
                visits: 4429,
              },
              {
                country: "Mozambique",
                visits: 92447,
              },
              {
                country: "Uganda",
                visits: 20423,
              },
              {
                country: "Gibraltar",
                visits: 154,
              },
              {
                country: "Aruba",
                visits: 589,
              },
              {
                country: "Palestinian Territories",
                visits: 1117,
              },
              {
                country: "Afghanistan",
                visits: 109527,
              },
              {
                country: "Bermuda",
                visits: 182,
              },
              {
                country: "Northern Mariana Islands",
                visits: 114,
              },
              {
                country: "Tanzania",
                visits: 72457,
              },
              {
                country: "Namibia",
                visits: 10649,
              },
              {
                country: "Yemen",
                visits: 3683,
              },
              {
                country: "Cayman Islands",
                visits: 197,
              },
              {
                country: "Guyana",
                visits: 1003,
              },
              {
                country: "Turks and Caicos Islands",
                visits: 219,
              },
              {
                country: "Reunion",
                visits: 601,
              },
              {
                country: "US Virgin Islands",
                visits: 306,
              },
              {
                country: "Senegal",
                visits: 11315,
              },
              {
                country: "Isle of Man",
                visits: 357,
              },
              {
                country: "Bahamas",
                visits: 868,
              },
              {
                country: "Greenland",
                visits: 58,
              },
              {
                country: "Brunei Darussalam",
                visits: 1384,
              },
              {
                country: "Central African Republic",
                visits: 1274,
              },
              {
                country: "Madagascar",
                visits: 1709,
              },
              {
                country: "Mali",
                visits: 12544,
              },
              {
                country: "Lesotho",
                visits: 1023,
              },
              {
                country: "Myanmar",
                visits: 1417086,
              },
              {
                country: "Benin",
                visits: 7373,
              },
              {
                country: "Fiji",
                visits: 1886,
              },
              {
                country: "Saint Lucia",
                visits: 309,
              },
              {
                country: "Cameroon",
                visits: 17148,
              },
              {
                country: "Malawi",
                visits: 9080,
              },
              {
                country: "Sierra Leone",
                visits: 2090,
              },
              {
                country: "Comoros",
                visits: 208,
              },
              {
                country: "Jamaica",
                visits: 2691,
              },
              {
                country: "Papua New Guinea",
                visits: 2399,
              },
              {
                country: "Unspecified",
                visits: 1551,
              },
              {
                country: "Gambia",
                visits: 1319,
              },
              {
                country: "Swaziland",
                visits: 1297,
              },
              {
                country: "Zimbabwe",
                visits: 94964,
              },
              {
                country: "Niger",
                visits: 12674,
              },
              {
                country: "Paraguay",
                visits: 9457,
              },
              {
                country: "Congo",
                visits: 5117,
              },
              {
                country: "Djibouti",
                visits: 3779,
              },
              {
                country: "Guinea",
                visits: 4043,
              },
              {
                country: "Liberia",
                visits: 2214,
              },
              {
                country: "Mauritania",
                visits: 2108,
              },
              {
                country: "Turkmenistan",
                visits: 11514,
              },
              {
                country: "Botswana",
                visits: 11685,
              },
              {
                country: "Sudan",
                visits: 1635,
              },
              {
                country: "Grenada",
                visits: 229,
              },
              {
                country: "Sao Tome and Principe",
                visits: 1445,
              },
              {
                country: "Trinidad and Tobago",
                visits: 1985,
              },
              {
                country: "Gabon",
                visits: 3015,
              },
              {
                country: "Nicaragua",
                visits: 114630,
              },
              {
                country: "French Polynesia",
                visits: 193,
              },
              {
                country: "New Caledonia",
                visits: 359,
              },
              {
                country: "Suriname",
                visits: 523,
              },
              {
                country: "Vanuatu",
                visits: 374,
              },
              {
                country: "Haiti",
                visits: 20726,
              },
              {
                country: "French Guiana",
                visits: 212,
              },
              {
                country: "Timor-Leste",
                visits: 832,
              },
              {
                country: "Mayotte",
                visits: 235,
              },
              {
                country: "Bhutan",
                visits: 2311,
              },
              {
                country: "Togo",
                visits: 4470,
              },
              {
                country: "Guam",
                visits: 1497,
              },
              {
                country: "Eritrea",
                visits: 3033,
              },
              {
                country: "Solomon Islands",
                visits: 429,
              },
              {
                country: "Samoa",
                visits: 92,
              },
              {
                country: "Dominica",
                visits: 193,
              },
              {
                country: "Jersey",
                visits: 309,
              },
              {
                country: "Guernsey",
                visits: 218,
              },
              {
                country: "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)",
                visits: 7,
              },
              {
                country: "Europe (Unknown Country)",
                visits: 209,
              },
              {
                country: "Martinique",
                visits: 428,
              },
              {
                country: "Saint Vincent and The Grenadines",
                visits: 188,
              },
              {
                country: "Burkina Faso",
                visits: 9094,
              },
              {
                country: "Palau",
                visits: 142,
              },
              {
                country: "Sint Maarten",
                visits: 132,
              },
              {
                country: "Marshall Islands",
                visits: 83,
              },
              {
                country: "Kiribati",
                visits: 66,
              },
              {
                country: "Tonga",
                visits: 120,
              },
              {
                country: "Curacao",
                visits: 474,
              },
              {
                country: "Antarctica",
                visits: 165,
              },
              {
                country: "Anguilla",
                visits: 220,
              },
              {
                country: "Federated States of Micronesia",
                visits: 117,
              },
              {
                country: "American Samoa",
                visits: 92,
              },
              {
                country: "British Indian Ocean Territory",
                visits: 3,
              },
              {
                country: "Cook Islands",
                visits: 26,
              },
              {
                country: "Norfolk Island",
                visits: 7,
              },
              {
                country: "Tuvalu",
                visits: 6,
              },
              {
                country: "Niue",
                visits: 6,
              },
              {
                country: "Christmas Island",
                visits: 8,
              },
              {
                country: "Saint Martin",
                visits: 43,
              },
              {
                country: "Nauru",
                visits: 16,
              },
              {
                country: "Montserrat",
                visits: 6,
              },
              {
                country: "Saint Barthelemy",
                visits: 16,
              },
              {
                country: "St. Pierre and Miquelon",
                visits: 3,
              },
              {
                country: "North Korea",
                visits: 90,
              },
            ],
            joinBy: ["name", "country"],
            name: "Visits",
            colorKey: "visits",
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: false,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.map {
  min-height: 500px;
}
</style>


link to sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/highcharts-vue-demo-forked-9k8s7s
How do you download data to CSV?

you have to change the order of registering. HighchartsExporting(Highcharts) should come before HighchartsExportData(Highcharts). As to why I'm not sure but the script ordering in this helped
HighchartsAccessibility(Highcharts);
HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);
HighchartsExportData(Highcharts);


Upon initialization, the export-data module checks if exporting is registered, and if not it doesn't register itself, thus order of initializing modules is important.

yeah @jedrzejruta it looks like middleware registering. haven't used highcharts so dont really know the internals
